# How to clean up COM references in .NET when app will be left running?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, com, com-interop

I am working on a .NET program that starts a new instance of Excel, does some work, then ends, but must leave Excel running.  Later, when the program runs again, it will attempt to hook into the previous instance.

What is the best way to handle the releasing of COM objects in this situation?  If I do not do a "ReleaseComObject" on the app object the first time, then on the second run get the active object, then finally release the com object, do I have a memory leak?

The following simplified code illustrates what I am trying to do:

```
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlsApp;
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlsWb;

public void RunMeFirst()
{
    //Start a new instance
    System.Type oSEType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
    xlsApp = Activator.CreateInstance(oSEType);
    xlsWb = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\test1.xls");

    //Do some stuff

    xlsWb.Close(false);
    Cleanup(ref xlsWb);

    //Do not quit Excel here
    //No Cleanup of xlsApp here?  Is this OK?

    System.Environment.Exit(0);
}

public void RunMeSecond()
{
    //Hook into existing instance
    xlsApp = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
    xlsWb = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\test2.xls");

    //Do some stuff

    xlsWb.Close(false);
    Cleanup(ref xlsWb);

    xlsApp.Quit();
    Cleanup(ref xlsApp);

    System.Environment.Exit(0);
}

public void Cleanup(ref object theObj)
{
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(theObj);
    theObj = null;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: shouldn't your GC calls be _after_ you release the COM object?

Comment: Why should there be any GC calls at all?

Comment: This guy seems to make a good case for putting it first: http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=160433.  I've seen it the other way too, and, others say it is not necessary at all.  I am open to all comments and suggestions.

Comment: Kind of off tangent but I think xlsApp.Workbooks.Open() is creating an anonomous reference to a Workbooks object that isn't being released. Try xlsWbs = xlsApp.Workbooks; xlsWb = xlsWbs.Open()

Comment: // Do not quite the app.  That's not a great comment on a call to Environment.Exit().

Comment: To clarify, I meant, do not quit the COM app (i.e., the excel reference via .Quit).  My .NET app does indeed quit...  The System.Environment.Exit(0) line was just to illustrate that in my simplified example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, when working with the Office PIAs, i've found that these sorts of problems with objects not being released arise when you have instance variables that hold COM objects. In your case, these would be `xlsApp` and `xlsWb`. You don't have to quit the Excel application in order to release the objects, but you *do* have to perform the following as a cleanup procedure:

```
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlsWb);
xlsWb = null;

Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlsApp);
xlsApp = null;

GC.Collect();
```

Local-scoped variables containing COM objects don't seem to cause this problem, only instance variables. I hope this helps!

Comment: The problem is this... I can't call Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlsApp) in my first run, else Excel will close (I've tried it).  So, I'm wondering if it is OK to skip the FinalReleaseCOMObject if I intend to leave Excel running.  In the subsequent run of my .NET app, I will GetActiveObject then finally quit Excel then call FinalReleaseCOMObject.  Thoughts?

Comment: Excel shouldn't close just from calling `FinalReleaseComObject`... It should only close on `Quit`. Make sure that the `Interactive` and `Visible` properties are set to `true` before you release the application object and it shouldn't terminate when you clean up.

Comment: Nice catch.  That was it.  Interactive and Visible are both False in my actual program as it will be running on a server (I know, not ideal, but a necessary evil in this case).  I tried leaving the app Interactive, but the FinalReleaseCOMObject still terminates Excel.  Only when I leave Visible = True does the Release not terminate Excel.  Now why would that matter?

Comment: I guess Excel is 'clever' enough (well, it would be clever to do so on the desktop, but not a server) to terminate itself if its main window is invisible and the program that started it has detached. Not much you can do about this behaviour, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a tad confused - at the end of `RunMeFirst` you exit the process, so is `RunMeSecond` run in a different process from the first method or the same process?

Either way I would change your code so that `xlsWb` is scoped locally and just do the following:

```
public void RunMeFirst()
{
    System.Type oSEType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
    xlsApp = Activator.CreateInstance(oSEType);
    Workbook xlsWb = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\test1.xls");

    // Do stuff
    xlsWb.Close(false);

    System.Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

You shouldn't really call any of the `ReleaseComObject` methods except in certain circumstances (for example in server applications where many COM objects will all be in use and so it is critical to release objects as soon as possible).  The usual mechanism for cleaning up COM object should simply be to let them go out of scope, in which case the COM object will be released using the same magic the GC uses (I believe that it is cleaned up as the finalizer is run, but I'm not 100% sure on this).

The reason why its a good idea to scope `xlsWb` locally (rather than as a class member or a static member) is that class members will only be cleaned up when the class is cleaned up, and static members are *never* cleaned up until the appdomain is unloaded.  If you do need to clean up a COM object referenced by a static field then the way to do this is to set the static field to `null` so the underlying COM object can be cleaned up by the GC scoping rules:

```
xlsWb = null;
```

Also there should be no real need to call `GC.Collect` for similar reasons - Mike Rosenblum gives a fair explanation as to why he's calling `GC.Collect` and `ReleaseComObject`, but no real justification as to why he isn't just satisfied with letting the garbage collector do its job.  Like I said, there are situations where you might want more control over the release of COM objects, however these are the exception not the rule.

You may also find reading [Marshal.ReleaseComObject Considered Dangerous](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/01/marshal-releasecomobject-considered-dangerous.aspx) useful.