# Excel is not closing after this method

Tags: c#, excel, com

I can't close excel after this method. I tried to use some methods that I found in StackOverflow but I couldn't seem to be getting anywhere. Kindly can you take a look what am I doing wrong? Thank you!

```
    public void readAllFromXLS()
    {
        Excel.Application refExcel = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook refFile = refExcel.Workbooks.Open(Application.StartupPath + "\\Resources\\reference files\\price list.xlsx");
        try
        {
            string workSheet;
            if (Form1.sesion.isSRA)
                workSheet = "SRA";
            else
                workSheet = "Standard";
            Excel.Worksheet refSheet = refFile.Sheets[workSheet] as Excel.Worksheet;
            for (int row = 2; row <= refSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                Some Cell Reading Here...
            }
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(refSheet);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            DialogResult r = MessageBox.Show("Price List Excel File Error.", "File Read Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            Application.Exit();
            Console.WriteLine("------");
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(refFile);
        refExcel.Quit();
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(refExcel);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clean up COM references in .NET when app will be left running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957924/how-to-clean-up-com-references-in-net-when-app-will-be-left-running)

Comment: Is there a reason you are calling `refExcel.Quit()` **after** `GC.Collect`?

Comment: @ MickyD, thank you for the link I have already seen it, I can't see what is wrong with what am I doing.

Comment: @mjwills thank you for looking at it, I was just trying different versions to see if it will help my situation.

Comment: If you want to use the `GC.Collect` technique then you definitely need to call `refExcel.Quit()` **first**. Then, in the function that **calls** `readAllFromXLS` do `GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();`, repeated three times.

Answer (score 0):

In his book ".NET Development for Micorsoft Office". Andrew Whitechapel recommended forcing garbage collection to run twice.

Here is some example code from [his blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2008/08/13/comaddins-race-condition/)

```
if (excel != null)
{
    excel.Quit();
    excel = null;
}
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

As already pointed out, you must call Quit before the garbage collection.

I have used this technique successfully, but have now switched to the [OpenXML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx), which I find much better than Excel automation. In fact [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML) might be even better, but I have not used it yet.

Comment: Thank you for the GC suggestion, I will do that from now on. I hate the MS COM service but I have no other option at the moment. Regards.